# What is different between magento-coding-standard and marketplace-eqp?

Tags: extensions, magento2.3, marketplace, coding-standards

In Magento Marketplace Technical Review
It will Check The Coding standard of the Extension So I Need To Check in My Local Machine

But I have Found 3 Solution and I am confused what is better Solution.

> 1 [magento-coding-standard](https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard)
>
> 2 [marketplace-eqp](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-eqp)
>
> 3 [extdn-phpcs](https://github.com/extdn/extdn-phpcs)

I am developing my extension for Magento 2.3.* So I need To setup Coding Standard in my local machine for checking the quality of my extension`s code

I Need to Know the Difference Between this Two.

Which is better

> standalone application for checking

or

> Use within your Magento 2 project

Provide me Simple steps to install Magento coding standard.

Comment: Some link on this theme https://twitter.com/elevinskii/status/1122818224377204736?s=19

Answer (score 1):

> 1 magento-coding-standard
>   2 marketplace-eqp
>   3 extdn-phpcs

1 replaced 2 so use 1.  3 is something else. Use 1.

> Use within your Magento 2 project

This approach. However just scan the folder you are working on eg `app/code/Vendor/Module`

Install via composer

`composer require magento/magento-coding-standard`

Scan with something like this

`vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Magento2 app/code/Xigen/Vehicle`

Maybe you need to update phpcs

`composer require squizlabs/php_codesniffer:^3.4`

Comment: it will provide me Uncaught Error: Class 'PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner' not found in C:\xampp72\htdocs\Magento232\vendor\bin\phpcs:17

Comment: Did you update phpcs? Have you previously installed phpcs using a different method?